# How to sort a list of lists using the Stream API?

Tags: java

I want to output all names starting with the letter "A" and sort them in reverse alphabetical order using the Stream API.  The result should look like this: Ann, Andrew, Alex, Adisson. How do I do this?

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("John", "Ann"),
            Arrays.asList("Alex", "Andrew", "Mark"),
            Arrays.asList("Neil", "Adisson", "Bob")
    );
    List<List<String>> sortedList = list.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.startsWith("A"))
            Comparator.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: `List<String> sortedList = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(s -> s.startsWith("A")).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are assigning the result to a `List<List<String>>` it appears you want to filter and sort each list and then print them.  Here is how it might be done.

- Stream the list of lists.
- then stream each individual list and:

  - apply the filter
  - sort in reversed order using [Comparator.reverseOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder())
- then return that as a list
- and combine those lists into another list.

```
List<List<String>> sortedLists = list.stream()
        .map(lst -> lst.stream()
                .filter(o -> o.startsWith("A"))
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).toList())
    .toList();
for(List<String> lst : sortedLists) {
    System.out.println(lst);
}
```

prints (given your data).

```
[Ann]
[Andrew, Alex]
[Adisson]
```

If, on the other hand you want to combine the lists into one applying the same requirements, then:

- stream the list of lists
- flatMap them to put all of the list contents into a single stream.
- then apply the filter and sort methods.
- and collect into a list.

```
List<String> sortedList = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
             .filter(o->o.startsWith("A"))
             .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
             .toList();

for (String name : sortedList) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

prints

```
Ann
Andrew
Alex
Adisson
```